# Pass a parameter to PHP function with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, parameters, parameter-passing

I should use JavaScript to call a PHP function in another file, and I would like to pass a parameter in the AJAX call to the PHP function

This is my JS function:

```
    setInterval(function () {
    var url = <?php echo json_encode($con); ?>;
    var valuereq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    valuereq.open("GET", url, true);
    valuereq.send();
    valuereq.status;
    valuereq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (valuereq.readyState == 4 && valuereq.status == 200) {
            var return_data = valuereq.responseText;
            document.getElementById("conta").innerHTML = "Eseguito: " + return_data;
        }
        else document.getElementById("conta").innerHTML = valuereq.status;
    }

}, 2000);
```

This is my PHP funtion in the another file:

```
function conta($mail){
    global $wpdb, $table_name;
    echo $table_name;
   $count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT contatore FROM $table_name WHERE email = '$mail'");
   if($count!=NULL)
    echo "$count";
   else echo "inactive";
   echo "$wpdb->last_error";
}

// call the function and pass the parameters
conta($mail);
```

Is there a way to pass the "$mail" parameter inside the HttpRequest with AJAX?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: _Side note:_ You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use [$wpdb->prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) when building the query. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Thank you very much I will do it now. How can i escape user input too? should i use htmlspecialchars? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` is _not_ a safe way to escape user input for DB security. Please click on `$wpdb->prepare()` in my previous comment and read about how to use it. With that, you don't need to escape the data manually.

Comment: Thank you very much I will learn about it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you use `GET` , you can pass the parameter after the `url` like this

```
valuereq.open("GET", url+'?email=emailvalue', true);
```